# Finite difference estimation of partial derivatives for arbitrary grids in python

Tags: python, performance, mathematics, numerical-methods

I am currently working on testing some codes on python to solve differential equations by finite differences, but some problems and equations i am dealing with are:

1. Too big to keep manually writing it without heavy risk of mistakes
2. Often contain nonuniform grids which makes the usual evenly spaced grids finite differences to not apply.

Therefore, to prevent mistakes and to avoid exhaustive handpicking of equations, I decided to make a function that estimates partial derivatives for both arbitrary grids.

What the code does:

1. Obtains the dependent variable(the one which is to be differentiated)
2. Obtains the independent variable(basically the discretized grid points)
3. Checks the dimension of the variable to be differentiated
4. Checks in what dimension should the derivative be performed, for instance, for a 3D variable with entries [i,j,k] the partial derivative could be relative to i,j,or k.

Then it returns the partial derivative for each entry of the variable, using the Forward Finite Difference method for inner points and one-sided difference for boundary.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
from scipy import optimize
import pandas as pd
from numba import njit

@njit
def partial(var,var2,dim):
    y = var
    x = var2
    vardim = var.ndim
    invalid_input = 0
    
    #Forward
    
    if vardim == 1 and dim == 1:
        dydx = np.zeros(len(y))
        
        for i in range(len(dydx)):
            if i == len(dydx) - 1:
                dydx[i] =( (-1/(x[i-2]-x[i]) - 1/(x[i-1]-x[i]))        * y[i] 
                        -(x[i-2]-x[i])/((x[i-1]-x[i-2])*(x[i-1]-x[i])) * y[i-1] 
                        +(x[i-1]-x[i])/((x[i-1]-x[i-2])*(x[i-2]-x[i])) * y[i-2] )
            else:    
                dydx[i] = (y[i+1] - y[i])/(x[i+1] - x[i])
            
    elif vardim == 2 and dim == 1:
        dydx = np.zeros((len(y[:,0]), len(y[0,:])))
        
        for i in range(len(dydx[:,0])):
            for j in range(len(dydx[0,:])):
                if i == len(dydx[:,0]) - 1:
                    dydx[i,j] =( (-1/(x[i-2]-x[i]) - 1/(x[i-1]-x[i]))        * y[i,j] 
                              -(x[i-2]-x[i])/((x[i-1]-x[i-2])*(x[i-1]-x[i])) * y[i-1,j] 
                              +(x[i-1]-x[i])/((x[i-1]-x[i-2])*(x[i-2]-x[i])) * y[i-2,j] )
                else:         
                    dydx[i,j] = (y[i+1,j] - y[i,j])/(x[i+1] - x[i])
    
    elif vardim == 2 and dim == 2:
        dydx = np.zeros((len(y[:,0]), len(y[0,:])))
        
        for i in range(len(dydx[:,0])):
            for j in range(len(dydx[0,:])):
                if j == len(dydx[0,:]) - 1:
                    dydx[i,j] =( (-1/(x[j-2]-x[j]) - 1/(x[j-1]-x[j]))        * y[i,j] 
                              -(x[j-2]-x[j])/((x[j-1]-x[j-2])*(x[j-1]-x[j])) * y[i,j-1] 
                              +(x[j-1]-x[j])/((x[j-1]-x[j-2])*(x[j-2]-x[j])) * y[i,j-2] )                 
                else:    
                    dydx[i,j] = (y[i,j+1] - y[i,j])/(x[j+1] - x[j])
                
    elif vardim == 3 and dim == 1:
        dydx = np.zeros((len(y[:,0,0]), len(y[0,:,0]), len(y[0,0,:])))
        
        for i in range(len(dydx[:,0,0])):
            for j in range(len(dydx[0,:,0])):
                for k in range(len(dydx[0,0,:])):
                    if i == len(dydx[:,0,0]) - 1:
                        dydx[i,j,k] =( (-1/(x[i-2]-x[i]) - 1/(x[i-1]-x[i]))        * y[i,j,k] 
                                    -(x[i-2]-x[i])/((x[i-1]-x[i-2])*(x[i-1]-x[i])) * y[i-1,j,k] 
                                    +(x[i-1]-x[i])/((x[i-1]-x[i-2])*(x[i-2]-x[i])) * y[i-2,j,k] )                 
                    else:
                        dydx[i,j,k] = (y[i+1,j,k] - y[i,j,k])/(x[i+1] - x[i])
                        
    elif vardim == 3 and dim == 2:
        dydx = np.zeros((len(y[:,0,0]), len(y[0,:,0]), len(y[0,0,:])))
        
        for i in range(len(dydx[:,0,0])):
            for j in range(len(dydx[0,:,0])):
                for k in range(len(dydx[0,0,:])):
                    if j == len(dydx[0,:,0])-1:
                        dydx[i,j,k] =( (-1/(x[j-2]-x[j]) - 1/(x[j-1]-x[j]))        * y[i,j,k] 
                                    -(x[j-2]-x[j])/((x[j-1]-x[j-2])*(x[j-1]-x[j])) * y[i,j-1,k] 
                                    +(x[j-1]-x[j])/((x[j-1]-x[j-2])*(x[j-2]-x[j])) * y[i,j-2,k] ) 
                    else:
                        dydx[i,j,k] = (y[i,j+1,k] - y[i,j,k])/(x[j+1] - x[j])
                        
    elif vardim == 3 and dim == 3:
        dydx = np.zeros((len(y[:,0,0]), len(y[0,:,0]), len(y[0,0,:])))
        
        for i in range(len(dydx[:,0,0])):
            for j in range(len(dydx[0,:,0])):
                for k in range(len(dydx[0,0,:])):
                    if k == len(dydx[0,0,:]) - 1:
                        dydx[i,j,k] =( (-1/(x[k-2]-x[k]) - 1/(x[k-1]-x[k]))        * y[i,j,k] 
                                    -(x[k-2]-x[k])/((x[k-1]-x[k-2])*(x[k-1]-x[k])) * y[i,j,k-1] 
                                    +(x[k-1]-x[k])/((x[k-1]-x[k-2])*(x[k-2]-x[k])) * y[i,j,k-2] )    
                    else:
                        dydx[i,j,k] = (y[i,j,k+1] - y[i,j,k])/(x[k+1] - x[k])
    else:
        invalid_input = 1
                        
    if invalid_input == 1:
        raise ValueError('Invalid Input')                
    else:
        return dydx
```

I am already using njit to speed up the function, and it indeed is much faster than without it, but even so, this code is still much slower than writing out the equations manually and adds a bottleneck on the problem solving. Since i am dealing with systems that will contain thousands of variables, the difference in time gets significant.

Is there any way to improve the efficiency of the code above?

Thanks.

EDIT: Time test example

```
compile_function = partial(np.linspace(0,5,6),np.linspace(0,5,6),1)

Test_variable = np.linspace(0,10000000,10000001)
Test_grid = np.linspace(0,10000000,10000001)
t0 = time.time()
partial(Test_variable,Test_grid,1)
elapsed = time.time() - t0
print(elapsed)
0.04687905311584473
```

Comment: "_any way to improve the efficiency?_" Yes. But you've not given SO contributors the tools to contribute improvements. You complain that this code is "slow", yet you supply no timing results. Please update the question by [adding code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which generates some test data, assigns `t0 = time.time()`, requests a `partial()` result, and then assigns `elapsed = time.time() - t0`. There's half a dozen related subroutines in this giant function; it would be enough to focus on just the most interesting one of them.

Comment: Test example added.

Comment: Thank you. We have ten million calculations of `dydx[i] = (y[i + 1] - y[i]) / (x[i + 1] - x[i])` and one calculation that is more involved. On my 2.2 GHz MacBook Air I see ~ 60 msec runtimes. Apparently Intel branch prediction is very effective, as pulling the "test for last" out of the loop doesn't speed things up. I tried to drag vectorized routines like `np.reciprocal(np.diff(x))` into the mix, but with no improvement. JIT already gave ~ 100x speedup over interpreted bytecode. I don't think there's much fat to trim here. Memory bandwidth is the limiting factor. This code wins!

Comment: Thank you. I am very surprised that the multiple for loops do not actually bring down the performance a lot, perhaps its the njit optimization which does the trick. Indeed I only managed indeed to get a marginal improvement in speed by applying the corrections on the accepted answer below.

Comment: Ok, here is one constructive criticism. If we're limited by memory bandwidth, then... use less memory! If you can get away with `float32`, prefer that over `float64`.

Comment: Great! Thanks, @J_H. Seems like a very simple improvement for my usual runs. I always found it that my usual runs with float64 were giving me a level of accuracy that was very overkill for my needs.

Comment: It seems like this would be an ideal candidate to rewrite into C++ and just provide a Python binding if you really need every last bit of performance. Only thing you'd be losing out on is nice indexing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @J_H said. This is not properly answerable in its current state, but as a review of the code and standards.

### Split your code into simple functions

Instead of having your methods all in a block in the same `partial` function, divide your code into sub-functions:

```
def calc_diff_1d_dx(x, y)
    dydx = np.zeros(len(y))
        
    for i in range(len(dydx)):
        if i == len(dydx) - 1:
           dydx[i] =( (-1/(x[i-2]-x[i]) - 1/(x[i-1]-x[i]))        * y[i] 
                    -(x[i-2]-x[i])/((x[i-1]-x[i-2])*(x[i-1]-x[i])) * y[i-1] 
                    +(x[i-1]-x[i])/((x[i-1]-x[i-2])*(x[i-2]-x[i])) * y[i-2] )
        else:    
            dydx[i] = (y[i+1] - y[i])/(x[i+1] - x[i])
```

Then, your big select statement becomes:

```
    if vardim == 1 and dim == 1:
        calc_diff_1d_dx(x, y)           
    elif vardim == 2 and dim == 1:
        calc_diff_2d_dx(x, y)
    elif vardim == 2 and dim == 2:
        calc_diff_2d_dy(x, y)
    ...
```

This means we can then focus down on optimising/timing each of these independently.

### Testing

Before you ever start optimising, however, you need good testing, particularly regression testing, just to make sure that whatever you change doesn't affect your answer in a questionable way. A lot of optimisations can (and will) change your answer, but you have to be aware of what is an acceptable change in your circumstances. Does an absolute difference of `1e-10` affect your result? How about 1%? etc.

Without tests and a fully working code, there's no hope of optimising sensibly.

Tests also give us the benefit of a stable state to compare times with.

### Obvious efficiency gain

One obvious thing right away is that you're looping with `if`s in the loops to check whether you're on the final iteration. Stop your loop one early and evaluate the part in the if as a final step.

```py
       for i in range(len(dydx)):
            if i == len(dydx) - 1:
                dydx[i] =( (-1/(x[i-2]-x[i]) - 1/(x[i-1]-x[i]))        * y[i] 
                        -(x[i-2]-x[i])/((x[i-1]-x[i-2])*(x[i-1]-x[i])) * y[i-1] 
                        +(x[i-1]-x[i])/((x[i-1]-x[i-2])*(x[i-2]-x[i])) * y[i-2] )
            else:    
                dydx[i] = (y[i+1] - y[i])/(x[i+1] - x[i])
```

Becomes

```py
       for i in range(len(dydx)-1):
           dydx[i] = (y[i+1] - y[i])/(x[i+1] - x[i])

       i = len(dydx) - 1
       dydx[i] =( (-1/(x[i-2]-x[i]) - 1/(x[i-1]-x[i]))        * y[i] 
                -(x[i-2]-x[i])/((x[i-1]-x[i-2])*(x[i-1]-x[i])) * y[i-1] 
                +(x[i-1]-x[i])/((x[i-1]-x[i-2])*(x[i-2]-x[i])) * y[i-2] )
```

1. This makes things much clearer
2. You aren't performing a comparison every step of the loop and potentially branching. I'm not 100% sure on how Numba's JIT would optimise this, but this could kill many compiled languages' performance if they aren't smart enough to spot it.

### Further optimisation

In terms of general good techniques for optimisation, my first recommendation is to find a library which does what you want. Generally, you don't want to have to implement high-performance mathematical algorithms yourself except as a learning experience (unless they really definitely don't exist/are no longer supported).

In your code, you are using numpy, but doing looping through them in Python (something which should be avoided in optimising anyway), which is wasting the potential of numpy which has optimised, vectorised routines in C to do the heavy lifting. If you want it to be fast, you should be exploiting these as much as you can, rather than relying on JIT to get performance.

Comment: Thank you. I tested your solutions and got about 5% improvement in speed by removing the if statement inside the for loop. However doing the nested function approach, it actually slows down the code to about 3% slower than the original code, so i stayed with the "giant" function style. As for Numba over pure numpy, in my experience and browsing, numba can outperform np in many scenarios, while maitaining the easy to understand python style with the explicit use of the loops and explicit equations, which i prefer.

Comment: Also, Numpy doesn't have a function AFAIK that can do what i want. np.diff does not support different orders of accuracy or uneven spacing in the grid. A library that actually does what i want is Findiff https://github.com/maroba/findiff. But according to this theory page https://findiff.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/theory.html the code solves a system of linear equations when the function is called, so i doubt it will be faster. As currently i generate the coefficients in an external fast code and just copy paste the equation in the OP function. But i shall test it to confirm.

Comment: "_I tried to drag vectorized routines like `np.reciprocal(np.diff(x))` into the mix, but with no improvement._"  Sooo, what's "wrong" with those two numpy routines? Nothing. Until we **compose** them. We're gonna blow out L2 and probably L3 cache, fetching and re-fetching `x` values for first _this_ trivial computation and then _that_ one. Why does @Klaus3's solution win over numpy? Because we fetch a value from DRAM just once, and the JIT fixes up bytecode interpreter slowness. At ~ 6 nsec per array element, we're limited by memory bandwidth at this point, rather than compute speed.

Comment: Update on findiff: Yeah, just tested it and %timeit reports(the test is different than those in the OP, i used smaller arrays) about 240-270 microseconds for the equivalent of the derivatives of OP function. While OP function runs at about 1-1.2 microseconds, so about 200x slower. I know nothing about it but my suspicion is that the findiff functions do indeed solve the linear system of equations each time a different variable is called.

Comment: Did you try applying JIT independently to each of the separate functions? I don't see why it should slowdown. Besides, for legibility purposes only I would advise it. Also, if you're hurting code legibility and maintainability for 3% speedup, I feel that's really not worth it. For me, anything less than 10% is not worth considering.

Comment: I did, but it seems like this was the problem, i've read in the numba docs that they have limited support for nested functions. But in the end i think its best to split up the functions and make them work independently, each partial derivative for each variable dimension. Checking the dimension by myself is pretty obvious, the only tedious part is writing down the equation for different axis. This reduces the number of if conditions to be called, probably helps when i am going to call the function thousands of times in a solver.